# How to exploit Diffie-hellman to perform a man in the middle attack

Tags: diffie-hellman, man-in-the-middle

Im doing a project where Alice and Bob send each other messages using the Diffie-Hellman key-exchange. What is throwing me for a loop is how to incorporate the certificate they are using in this so i can obtain their secret messages.

From what I understand about MIM attakcs, the MIM acts as an imposter as seen on this diagram:

[image]

Below are the details for my project. I understand that they both have g and p agreed upon before communicating, but how would I be able to implement this with they both having a certificate to verify their signatures?

Alice prepares ⟨signA(NA, Bob), pkA, certA⟩ where signA is the digital signature algorithm used by Alice, “Bob” is Bob’s name, pkA is the public-key of Alice which equals gx mod p encoded according to X.509 for a fixed g, p as specified in the Diffie-Hellman key- exchange and certA is the certificate of Alice that contains Alice’s public-key that verifies the signature; Finally, NA is a nonce (random string) that is 8 bytes long.

Bob checks Alice's signature, and response with ⟨signB{NA,NB,Alice},pkB,certB⟩. Alice gets the message she checks her nonce NA and calculates the joint key based on pkA, pkB according to the Diffie-Hellman key exchange. Then Alice submits the message ⟨signA{NA,NB,Bob},EK(MA),certA⟩ to Bob and Bobrespondswith⟨SignB{NA,NB,Alice},EK(MB),certB⟩.

where MA and MB are their corresponding secret messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The internet can help!

> The Diffie-Hellman key exchange is vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle
>   attack. In this attack, an opponent Carol intercepts Alice's public
>   value and sends her own public value to Bob. When Bob transmits his
>   public value, Carol substitutes it with her own and sends it to Alice.
>   Carol and Alice thus agree on one shared key and Carol and Bob agree
>   on another shared key. After this exchange, Carol simply decrypts any
>   messages sent out by Alice or Bob, and then reads and possibly
>   modifies them before re-encrypting with the appropriate key and
>   transmitting them to the other party. This vulnerability is present
>   because Diffie-Hellman key exchange does not authenticate the
>   participants. Possible solutions include the use of digital signatures
>   and other protocol variants.

So you have your own value for A, and you just swap the message contents and recompute signatures and forward along.

Answer (score 6):

Offering [the Wikipedia answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Security):

> In the original description, the Diffie–Hellman exchange by itself
> does not provide authentication of the communicating parties and is
> thus vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack. A person in the middle
> may establish two distinct Diffie–Hellman key exchanges, one with
> Alice and the other with Bob, effectively masquerading as Alice to
> Bob, and vice versa, allowing the attacker to decrypt (and read or
> store) then re-encrypt the messages passed between them.
>
> A method to
> authenticate the communicating parties to each other is generally
> needed to prevent this type of attack. Variants of Diffie-Hellman,
> such as [STS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol), may be used instead to avoid these types of attacks.

You may consider impressing your professor by discussing [the variants of Diffie-Hellman that are more secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol). For now, given you've noted the original implementation, this will do.

Best of luck!